# How to use Gson instance in Serializer/Deserializer class?

Tags: java, gson

For example

```
public class HistoryRecordDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<HistoryRecord> {

    private LocalDateTimeConverter dateTimeConverter = new LocalDateTimeConverter();

    @Override
    public HistoryRecord deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(UUUID.fromString(json.get("user").get("id").getAsString()));
        OtherData data = new OtherData();
        data.setData(json.get("otherData").getAsLong());
        return UserAndData(user, otherData);
    }
```

As you can see, I instantiate `User` and `OtherData` manually, but I think there is a better solution. What is the best way to deserialize user with `fromJson(...)`? Should I pass Gson instance to `HistoryRecordDeserializer`? Should I create new one?

Comment: It depends what your POJO and Json look like. You could create new Gson  or use `JsonDeserializationContext context` `deserialize` method to deserializer objects

Comment: @varren when I last time tried to use `context.deserialize(json.get("id"), UUID.class, context)` it just return `null`. Why it so?

Comment: don't really know, but context is pretty much the same gson deserializer from above. If you gson can deserialize this, then context will be also able to do this. But it is fine to do it like you did in you post above

Comment: @varren I just tried `context.deserialize(jsonObj, type)` another time and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by using `JsonDeserializationContext`.

```
@Override
public HistoryRecord deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonObject object = json.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonObject extras = object.get("extraData").getAsJsonObject();

    HistoryRecord hr = object.context.deserialize(object.get("data"), HistoryRecord.class);
    hr.appendExtraData(extras, HistoryRecordExtraData.class);
    ...
    }
```

As @varren sad:

> If you Gson can deserialize this, then context will be also able to do this.

So, you can even apply another custom type adapter(`LocalDateTimeConverter`):

```
    gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeConverter())
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(HistoryRecord.class, new HistoryRecordDeserializer())
            .create();
```

and use it inside `HistoryRecordDeserializer`:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = context.deserialize(object.get("dateTime"), LocalDateTime.class);
```